# Conectarse a API (js) - Consultar precio - guardar precio (variable) en mysql - ejecutar cada hora

Tags: mysql, api, fetch, cronjobs

Necesito que cada cierto tiempo localhost se conecte a una api publica (https://api.ethplorer.io/getTokenInfo/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000?apiKey=freekey);

Leer el valor de data['0'].price.rate;

Leer el valor de data['0'].price.ts;

Y guardar esos dos valores en MySQL

Las busquedas en google me sugiere Node.js, veo ejemplos pero ninguno parecido.

Con js y php He logrado traer las variables "rate" y "ts" a un `<input id="rate">` y `<input id="ts">`
y con submit los mando a Mysql.

Quiero que eso se haga server (api) to server (localhost) automatico cada cierto tiempo (1 hora), pero no se que debo buscar ni por donde empezar.

Tengo XAMPP, Windows 11 (64bit).

Esto es lo que tengo:

**MySQL DataBase**

Tabla nombre "tabla"

id - Type (int) - Length (11) - Not null - Primary key

rate - Type (decimal) - Length (65) - Not Null

ts - Type (decimal) - Length (65) - Not null

**apical.js**

```
function traer(){
        Promise.all([
        fetch('https://api.ethplorer.io/getTokenInfo/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000?apiKey=freekey')])
    .then(function (responses) {
        return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }));
    })  .then(data =>{
            let rate = data['0'].price.rate;
            document.getElementById("rate").value = rate;
            let ts = data['0'].price.ts;
            document.getElementById("ts").value = ts;
        })}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="apicall.js" async></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onLoad="traer()">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Form</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Se cargan records desde apicall</p>
                    <form action="post.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Rate</label>
                            <input id="rate" type="text" name="rate" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Timestamp</label>
                            <input id="ts" type="text" name="ts" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php
    $servername='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    $dbname = "test";
    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,"$dbname");
      if(!$conn){
          die('Could not Connect MySql Server:' .mysql_error());
        }
?>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
     $rate = $_POST['rate'];
     $ts = $_POST['ts'];
     
     $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (rate,ts)
     VALUES ('$rate','$ts')";
     if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record has been added successfully !";
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . mysqli_error($conn);
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Si ya estás usando PHP, entonces escribe un script en PHP que haga la llamada a la API, obtenga los datos y los inserte en la BD. Para que se ejecute cada 1 hora puedes programar un cron job que llame a tu script PHP cada 1 hora y listo.

Comment: Excelente, exactamente asi quedó,
Hice un test.php, un cronjob.bat y lo meti a task scheduler

Comment: Perfecto. Lo único que faltaría es que des seguridad a tu código, porque como está ahora es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo considera usar consultas preparadas. Deberías también verificar que los datos que vas a insertar no son nulos ni vacíos.